# Exception sending file (greater than small size) with Spring security and Rest web services

Tags: java, spring, rest, sockets, spring-security

I added basic authentication to my Rest web service (created through Spring) but for RestTemplate I use with success this class:

```
public class RestClient extends RestTemplate {
    public RestClient(String username, String password) {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
        setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }
}
```

but for my `HttpPost` I'm using this:

```
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(null,-1),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build()){   
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverIp + "ATS/client/file");
        File file = new File(filePath);

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file);
        ContentBody cbPath= new StringBody(toStorePath,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        builder.addPart("file", cbFile);
        builder.addPart("toStorePath",cbPath);
        httppost.setEntity(builder.build());
        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (resEntity != null) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Response response = mapper.readValue(resEntity.getContent(), Response.class);
            EntityUtils.consume(resEntity) ;
            return response;
        }
        //It should never be thrown 
        else return new Response(false, false, "Error with server response" , null); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        return new Response(false, false,"Error sending the file!" , errorResponse);
    }
```

but the request doesn't arrive to server because client throws this exception:

```
    INFO 11284 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8086: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
2015-12-23 12:49:45.815  INFO 11284 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8086
2015-12-23 12:49:46.818  INFO 11284 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8086: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
2015-12-23 12:49:46.818  INFO 11284 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8086
2015-12-23 12:49:47.821  INFO 11284 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8086: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
2015-12-23 12:49:47.821  INFO 11284 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec   : Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8086
2015-12-23 12:49:48.825 ERROR 11284 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] client.controller.ErrorController        : org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8086/ATS/client/file":Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:330)
    at client.services.FileServicesImpl.sendFile(FileServicesImpl.java:116)
    at client.wbcontroller.ControllerMatlab.Write(ControllerMatlab.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:91)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
    ... 45 more
```

If I use a very small file, like 10Kb, all works ine, if I tray with 10MB file receive exception.

The same problem there is with the below code:

```
@Override
public Response sendFile(String username, String password, String serverIp, String toStorePath, String filePath) {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> mvm = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    mvm.add("file", new FileSystemResource(filePath));
    mvm.add("toStorePath",toStorePath);
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient(username, password);

    return restClient.postForObject(serverIp + "ATS/client/file", mvm, Response.class);
```

On the server I have this spring security configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
             http.csrf().disable()
             .antMatcher("/client/**")
             .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/client/file/**").permitAll()
//             
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .httpBasic();
        }
    }
```

If I add .antMatchers("/client/file/**").permitAll() (or rather I dasable authentication) it works.
The odd thing is that without authentication I can send file over 300MB (I use the method with HTTP post to use streaming file). 
How can I fix it? And with this method, user and password are hidden with https? I spend already 2 days. Thanks

Comment: Your server logs should show the reason, if it's the webserver who closes the connection prematurly. Additionally, logging the network traffic with tcpdump/wireshark/etc. could provide a hint on what is going on.

Comment: I updated with all stacktrace.The problem is on the client, the request doesn't arrive on server

Comment: @luca I have the same problem, do you already found the solution?

Comment: @esthrim if I remember with manually authentication it works, so I excluded the path from spring securety and make authentication with a specific method.